# Including files in ECR image

Tags: docker, containers, amazon-ecr

Just a quick question regarding images uploaded to ECR - are local files included? e.g. if I have something like:

```
FROM python:3.9.10-buster
RUN mkdir /app
WORKDIR /app
COPY script.sh /script.sh
ENTRYPOINT ["./script.sh"]
```

I'll build the image and upload it to a public ECR repository. Would users be able to run `./script.sh` from within the Docker image or will they need to have a file called `script.sh` on their computer?

Comment: Users sure can run `script.sh` by just running the docker image.

But your Dockerfile seems incorrect. You should guarantee that the script has executed permission and is called by the right path.

`
RUN chmod +x /script.sh
ENTRYPOINT ["/script.sh"]
`

Comment: If the script is checked into source control with execute permissions, that will be preserved when `docker build` copies it into the image.

Answer (score 0):

The `script.sh` file is certainly included in the image, there are two other problems that make the image not work in the end.

One was already mentioned in a comment by Ted, that being that `script.sh` may not be executable.

That being said, the problem that is likely causing you to think `script.sh` would not be included in the image, is that it's not in the working directory.
Your copy statement was

```
COPY script.sh /script.sh
```

Since the last part is `/script.sh`, beginning with a slash, the file will be put to the root of the image. However you already set the workdir to `/app`.
When the entrypoint is being loaded `script.sh` won't be found, since it's being searched for in the working directory.

Getting your image to work correctly should be as easy as removing that slash in the COPY statement, so the correct statement would be:

```
COPY script.sh script.sh
```

To resolve the possible problem of `script.sh` not being runnable, I'd recommend to make the entrypoint like this:

```
ENTRYPOINT ["sh", "script.sh"]
```

This way it doesn't matter weither or not the script is executable